# Nodejs Expressjs, Pass data to all routes?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I was new in NodeJs by using ExpressJs framework. I have to create a login system and I want my html sidebar menu always show which user was login by looking from session and join to the database.

In laravel I can do it by using **view composer**. How I can do that in ExpressJs with AngulaJs for this case.

Comment: It all depends on how you render your client (server side, client side), and how you handle the user login

Comment: What have you tried so far ? see how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an authentication system. When a user logins for the first time, the data should be sent from server to client and then save somewhere in storage so the menu can identify which user is logged in.